# Silverlight works in IE, blank page in other browsers

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml, silverlight-4.0, cross-browser, silverlight-5.0

I am new to SilverLight and I am trying to replicate a simple example from the book "Pro Silverlight 5 in C#" by Matthew MacDonald.

I am using VS2012 to create Silverlight 5 application.

When I run *SilverlightApplication1TestPage.html* - **it works in IE10, but in FF and Chrome I get a blank page**. The SilverLight plugin loads in these browsers but does not show anything.

Please give me any suggestions as to why this is happening.

The *MainPage.xaml* code is as follows.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="lblMessage" Text="Hello World!" Margin="5"></TextBlock>
        <Button x:Name="cmdClickMe" Content="Click Me!" Margin="5" Click="cmdClickMe_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The *MainPage.xaml.cs* contains the following handler.

```
 private void cmdClickMe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Goodbye, cruel world.";
    }
```

The html page looks as follows (the body portion).

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="source" value="SilverlightApplication1.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.0.61118.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
</form>
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: I posted the html <body> above.

Comment: You can run the link and see if silver light is working fine in firefox on your computer: http://bubblemark.com/silverlight2.html

Comment: The bubbles animation works fine in FF and Chrome.

Comment: I tested the project on another computer and it works there in IE10 and Chrome. So maybe there is something with the settings on my machine. Yet, the bubble test above works fine in the browsers on my machine.

Comment: can you run fiddler and see if the XAP is getting downloaded and also when you right click does it show 'Silverlight'? One last  (Advanced) thing you can do is, do try catch in app.xaml.cs and display message box with any exception is thrown?

Comment: The 'Silverlight' does appear when I right-click in FF and Chrome. The .xap file fails to download in FF and Chrome (but works in IE). The browser Console shows an error: "Could not download the Silverlight application. Check web server settings."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the Silverlight project directory was located under "C:\Users\<USER>\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects", where <USER> was not written in English.

I moved the .html and .xap files to C:\ and the projected worked fine in all browsers.